# Cant able to capture images

Tags: android

```
    public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    if (v.getId() == R.id.textView7)
                 {     
                        try {

                            Intent captureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                            startActivityForResult(captureIntent, CAMERA_CAPTURE);
                        }
                        catch(ActivityNotFoundException anfe)
                {

                            String errorMessage = "Whoops - your device doesn't support capturing images!";
                            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                            toast.show();
                        }
                    }
                }protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
                    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                        if(requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE){

                            picUri = data.getData();
                                                            performCrop();
                        }

                        else if(requestCode == PIC_CROP){

                            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();

                            Bitmap thePic = extras.getParcelable("data");

                            ImageView picView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

                            picView.setImageBitmap(thePic);
                        }
                        else if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
                                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                                selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
                                System.out.println("Image Path : " + selectedImagePath);
                                iv1.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);
                            }
                    }
                }


                private void performCrop(){

                    try {

                        Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP"); 

                        cropIntent.setDataAndType(picUri, "image/*");

                        cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");

                        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
                        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);

                        cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 256);
                        cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 256);

                        cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);

                        startActivityForResult(cropIntent, PIC_CROP);  
                    }

                    catch(ActivityNotFoundException anfe){

                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Mobile doesnot support this feature",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        toast.show();
                    }
        }

                public String getPath(Uri uri) {
                    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
                    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
                    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                    cursor.moveToFirst();
                    return cursor.getString(column_index);
                }
```

***i tried to capture an image using this by clicking on button doesnt shows anything by clicking on it
I have created a button to capture the image but it shows error!!
please help***

i am a newbie and wish to learn

Comment: what is the error in logcat?

Comment: Please give the logcat..

Comment: 09-04 07:36:55.427: E/AndroidRuntime(1118): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #5
09-04 07:36:55.427: E/AndroidRuntime(1118): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
09-04 07:36:55.427: E/AndroidRuntime(1118):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)

Comment: Please post your code containing doInBackground() module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this is working like charm with me**

```
private String selectedImagePath = "";
    final private int PICK_IMAGE = 1;
    final private int CAPTURE_IMAGE = 2;

public Uri setImageUri() {
        // Store image in dcim
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/DCIM/", "image" + new Date().getTime() + ".png");
        Uri imgUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        this.imgPath = file.getAbsolutePath();
        return imgUri;
    }


    public String getImagePath() {
        return imgPath;
    }

btnGallery.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, ""), PICK_IMAGE);

            }
        });

        btnCapture.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, setImageUri());
                startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE);
            }
        });

@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE) {
                selectedImagePath = getAbsolutePath(data.getData());
                imgUser.setImageBitmap(decodeFile(selectedImagePath));
            } else if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE) {
                selectedImagePath = getImagePath();
                imgUser.setImageBitmap(decodeFile(selectedImagePath));
            } else {
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            }
        }

    }


public Bitmap decodeFile(String path) {
        try {
            // Decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, o);
            // The new size we want to scale to
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 70;

            // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            int scale = 1;
            while (o.outWidth / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE && o.outHeight / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE)
                scale *= 2;

            // Decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize = scale;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, o2);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;

    }

public String getAbsolutePath(Uri uri) {
        String[] projection = { MediaColumns.DATA };
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaColumns.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        } else
            return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add below two lines in your manifest.

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
```